# Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in ORDER BY statement

Tags: sql-server

I am get Collation error after running the below procedure. Please someone help me in this regard. I am trying to collate between 2 schemas in x3v64 database.

begin

```
      SELECT "SALESREP"."REPNUM_0", "SALESREP"."REPNAM_0", 
      "srheader" ."customercode" ,"srheader" ."customername" ,"ITMMASTER"."TSICOD_0",
             "srdetail" ."productcode" ,"srdetail" ."productname" , "srdetail" ."packing" , "srdetail" ."stunit" ,"srdetail" ."unit", "ITMMASTER"."SAUSTUCOE_0",
             "srheader" ."voucherdate" , "srheader" ."vouchernumber" ,  1 AS "SNS_0",
             "srdetail" ."site" ,"srheader" ."delcomment","srheader" ."vouchertype" ,"srdetail" ."unit"  AS "TXNUNIT",
             "srdetail" ."qty" , "srdetail" ."netrate" ,
             "srdetail" ."grossamount" , "srdetail" ."discamt" ,  "srdetail" ."discamt" ,"srdetail" ."netamount"  AS "LINEAMOUNT",'' as "SONUM","srheader" ."vouchernumber"  as 'SR_NUM'

       into #tmp_sal
       FROM ("x3v64".dbo ."srheader"  "srheader" INNER JOIN 
             "x3v64".dbo ."srdetail"  "srdetail" ON "srheader" ."vouchernumber" ="srdetail" ."vouchernumber" ) INNER JOIN
              "x3v64"."AUJANX3"."ITMMASTER" "ITMMASTER" ON "srdetail"."productcode"  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ="ITMMASTER"."ITMREF_0" INNER JOIN
              "x3v64"."AUJANX3"."SALESREP" "SALESREP" ON "srheader" ."srep"   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = "SALESREP"."REPNUM_0" 


                UNION ALL

       SELECT "SALESREP"."REPNUM_0", "SALESREP"."REPNAM_0", 
              "SORDER"."BPCORD_0", "SORDER"."BPCNAM_0","ITMMASTER"."TSICOD_0",
              "SORDERP"."ITMREF_0","ITMMASTER"."ITMDES1_0", "ITMMASTER"."ITMDES3_0", "ITMMASTER"."STU_0","ITMMASTER"."SAU_0",  "ITMMASTER"."SAUSTUCOE_0",
              "SORDER"."ORDDAT_0", "SORDER"."SOHNUM_0",  1 AS "SNS_0",
              "SORDER"."SALFCY_0","SORDER"."ICTCTY_0" As "Comments", 'SOI',"SORDERP"."SAU_0" AS "TXNUNIT",
              "SORDERQ"."QTY_0", "SORDERP"."NETPRIATI_0",
              "SORDERP"."GROPRI_0", "SORDERP"."DISCRGVAL2_0", "SORDERP"."DISCRGVAL3_0", ("SORDERP"."NETPRIATI_0" * "SORDERQ"."QTY_0") AS "LINEAMOUNT",'' as "SONUM","SORDER"."PJT_0" as 'SR_NUM'

       FROM   ((("x3v64"."AUJANX3"."SORDER" "SORDER" INNER JOIN 
              "x3v64"."AUJANX3"."SALESREP" "SALESREP" ON "SORDER"."REP_0"="SALESREP"."REPNUM_0") INNER JOIN 
              "x3v64"."AUJANX3"."SORDERP" "SORDERP" ON "SORDER"."SOHNUM_0"="SORDERP"."SOHNUM_0") INNER JOIN 
              "x3v64"."AUJANX3"."SORDERQ" "SORDERQ" ON ("SORDERP"."SOHNUM_0"="SORDERQ"."SOHNUM_0")
                  AND ("SORDERP"."SOPLIN_0"="SORDERQ"."SOPLIN_0")) INNER JOIN 
              "x3v64"."AUJANX3"."ITMMASTER" "ITMMASTER" ON "SORDERP"."ITMREF_0"="ITMMASTER"."ITMREF_0" 

                 ORDER BY "srheader" ."vouchernumber" 
            select * from #tmp_sal
```

end

Comment: Well, then you need to COLLATE the columns using the appropriate collations.

Answer (score 0):

You change the collation in the JOIN conditions on the first SELECT statement so that you can compare the fields. But you also need to change the collation in the select list so that they can be inserted into the same temp table field. Example:

```
--this would fail with message "Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in ORDER BY statement.".  
SELECT ItemCode 'ItemCode' 
FROM [SAP database].dbo.rdr1 
UNION ALL
SELECT product 'ItemCode' 
FROM [other database].dbo.[other table] 
ORDER BY ItemCode

--this would succeed
SELECT ItemCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 'ItemCode' 
FROM [SAP database].dbo.rdr1 
UNION ALL
SELECT Product 'ItemCode' 
FROM [other database].dbo.[other table]  
ORDER BY ItemCode
```

If I removed the ORDER BY clause from the first SELECT statement the error message would read "Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in SELECT statement.".